# Good way to create relationship between django users only if both parties agree to the relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm looking to create a one-to-one relationship between two types of Django users. I want one user to initiate a request for relationship creation and I want to create it only if the second user agrees to it.

Is there a good way to remember the request to create the relationship but only actually create it once the second user agrees to it with Django?

Comment: you want it be done on a bigger scale  consider using a graph database.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    invite_user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    accept_user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then when a user send request for relationship, just create a record `Relationship` with `accepted=false` then if user accept, change to `accepted=true`. You can also add `created_at`, `accepted_at` also.

Comment: Looks good, I'll try it out!

Comment: Hey, I noticed you had `primary_key=True` on both fields, Django got mad at that. Just a heads up.

Comment: Sorry I copied it T_T, edited tho :D